# set Selector for Button Programmatically issues

Tags: android, xml, android-selector

I have a row of buttons and i am setting their selectors for background and text programatically. The reason i want to do this programmatically is because, I have a set of themes the user can choose from and depending upon the theme selected, i want to change the selector for the button.

For example, if the user selects a blue theme, when loaded, the background of the button is blue and text colour is white. When he presses the button, the background changes to white and the text colour changes to blue. When user removes the finger from button, the changes revert back to default blue for background and white for text colour. You can see the respective selectors for blue below.

This is similar to all other themes. I have separate XMLs for all the themes. The selector for text colour change works fine. The problem is with the background selector for button.

**`selector_background_blue.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue_500"/>

</selector>
```

**`color_selector.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue_500"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white"/>

</selector>
```

I have a class that returns the drawable(selector) depending upon the theme selected. I am getting the selector as follows:

```
public Drawable getButtonBackgrounds(String theme) {
    Drawable drawable = null;

    if (theme.equalsIgnoreCase(Const.Theme.BLUE))
        drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.selector_background_blue);

    return drawable;
}
```

I'm setting these selector for button's background as follows:

```
private void setButtonBackgrounds(Drawable buttonDrawable) {
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        if (sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            btnA.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable);
            btnT.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable);
            .....
            .....
            btnVoice.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable);
        } else {
            btnA.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
            btnT.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
            .....
            .....
            btnVoice.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
        }
}
```

button's `xml`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnT"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/button_t"
    android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Total Row's XML:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnA"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@string/arithmetic_symbol"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnT"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@string/trigonometric_symbol"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnN"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@string/voice_calculator_symbol"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnVC"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_voice_black"
                android:text="" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnC"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@string/button_c"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnD"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="@string/button_del"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

This is the same for all the buttons in the row.

The drawable is set just fine on the load. Please refer to the image below.

[image]

The problem is When I click on a button(for ex., A), the adjacent ImageButton(microphone) is also changing its state. Please look at the images below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Why is this happening? Can someone help me with this. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: What's the class of these buttons' container? I mean, are they contained within LinearLayout, FrameLayout or something else? Do you have any listeners attached to these buttons?

Comment: They are inside linear layout.. Will update question with XML in 1 hr

Comment: @aga, updated question with row's xml. Each button has an onClickListener attached to it.

Comment: And what happens in these `OnClickListener`s? I don't see any issues with the layout itself, though it seems a bit strange for me: you didn't specify the `weightSum` of buttons' container, and you've set container height to 0dip and weight to 1. Is this container contained within another LinearLayout or is it just some irrelevant code which can be safely removed?

Comment: Basically it is a calculator app. This layout is inside another layout that has around 6 to 7 linear layouts with weight 1. In the onClickListener s, When A is clicked, a group of buttons in the rest of the layouts gets hidden and another set of buttons appear. Same with V and T.  C and DEL are just delete and clear buttons

Comment: Ok, what happens when you remove `btnN` completely? Does the issue still persists?
P.S. is this code open-sourced, or proprietary one? I mean, can I take a look at this code, try to install it on emulator or something?

Comment: The problem still persists. Also if i remove background selector for microphone image button, some other random button is getting highlighted. I can't provide the code at this moment. I can try to add parts of the code if needed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think that you are experiencing a **mutate**-related issue (please take a look [here](http://www.curious-creature.com/2009/05/02/drawable-mutations/comment-page-1/), it's extremly useful)

You need to call [`mutate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate()) on your drawable before assingning it to the `View` if yout don't want to share the *common state* across the various instances:

```
Drawable buttonDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn);
buttonDrawable.mutate()
btnA.setBackgroundDrawable(buttonDrawable);
```

In your code you are using the same `Drawable` for more then one `View`, so you need to adopt the approach I've described above to avoid the state-sharing.

Comment: Man you saved my life.. Seems to work.. +1 till i test the application throughly and award you the bounty.

Comment: @VamsiChalla glad to hear this. Let us know if you have any other issues with that.

Comment: I have one more small issue, i have a textview and i need it to be scrollable, so i am using mTextViewExpression.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); in the code. But, when i set the text to empty using mTextViewExpression.setText(""); it doesn't clear itself. Is there anything that i am missing in this?

Comment: @VamsiChalla try to set `mTextViewExpression.setMovementMethod(null)` and then `mTextViewExpression.setText("");` Anyway I suggest you to start a new question because this is a completely different topic ;)

Comment: I did not need to use the .mutate() for a Drawable selector I used.

Drawable selector = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_selector);
            this.setBackgroundDrawable(selector);

Comment: @bonnyz I am creating a StateListDrawable dynamically for radio buttons backgrounds. I am setting this background for 2 radio buttons. But, I am facing same issue for both the radio buttons the state is changing, if I change for one.

Answer (score 1):

Dude You have to set the selector From The XML File See below:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnT"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.20"
android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
android:text="@string/button_t"
android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Here The property `android:background="@drawable/you_drawable_selector"` is where you have to set The Selector.

Hope I helped.

Comment: I know, but my selectors change depending on the theme the user chooses and hence I am setting the selectors programatically.

Comment: Take a good look at this method : 
private void setButtonBackgrounds(Drawable buttonDrawable)

Comment: tell me one thing. When you execute the Method 'setButtonBackgrounds' what are u really hoping to achieve.

Comment: This is the flow. User selects a theme(black, blue, etc.,) and I have a class with a method that returns the appropriate drawable for the selected theme and I am setting that drawable to all the buttons in my view. Drawable buttonDrawable = color.getButtonBackgrounds(theme); where color is the object of CustomClass. Here is how i am returning the drawable from getButtonBackgrounds() -> if (theme.equalsIgnoreCase(Const.Theme.BLACK))
   drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(
     R.drawable.selector_background_black);

Comment: You see as u listed on the top that Your Problem is when u click The Button T The color of the other buttons also change. It Should be the problem with the OnClick. try to run the app again and also see the 'LogCat' when u click the button. it will show u what's wrong.

Comment: Okie.. Will check and get back to you at a later time.. Got some other work now.. Thanks for your help