# How to change the selector/ripple color on a standard button?

Tags: android, button, themes, selector

I'm using a standard button in my layout:

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/earlier_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="earlier"/>
```

And I figured out how to change it's color without changing it's default style:

```
earlierButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.earlier_button);
earlierButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_500), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

My question is now, how can I set a new selector/ripple or change the color of the current one? Does anyone know the default theme/style, which needs to be overwritten for that? Talking about these buttons:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set selector.

See this link for detail. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431028/850347

You have Button,

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/earlier_button"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="earlier"/>
```

And you may have selecor,

**btn_selecor.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

- btn_normal, btn_pressed is png images.
- Note that this btn_selecor.xml must be placed folder name "drawable"

Finally, set selector to your button programmatically.

```
    Drawable buttonDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_selector);
    buttonDrawable.mutate();
    btn1.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
```

**Edit1:**
Sure, you can set android default button selector by using code below.
In this case, you don't need to make your own selector.

```
Drawable buttonDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
buttonDrawable.mutate();
btn1.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I want to use the standard button style android provides and not creating own pngs. Is it somehow possible to set a custom style with androids btn_pressed as parent and change its color?